# Debit and Credit for Savings Class

Tags: java

I have an abstract class that has 4 methods for crediting, debiting, depositing and withdrawing. I am stuck on how I should go about setting up the methods for crediting and debiting the account, since I would assume it would be the same as deposit and withdrawal, but I don't believe it is. There is already a test-harness that she gave us, so I just need to setup the classes. This is the abstract class

```
  abstract public class Account implements PostInterest
    {
      private String fName;
      private String lName;
      private String nbrSSN;
      private char acctStatus = 'A';
      private double balance = 0.0;

      //five-argument constructor
      public Account(String first, String last, String ssn, char status, double begBalance)
      {
        setName(first);
        setLast(last);
        setSSN(ssn);
        setStatus(status);
        setBalance(begBalance);
      }

      public Account(String first, String last, String ssn)
      {
         setName(first);
        setLast(last);
        setSSN(ssn);
      }

      public void setName(String first)
      {
        fName = first;
      }

      public String getName()
      {
        return fName;
      }

      public void setLast(String last)
      {
        lName = last;
      }

      public String getLast()
      {
        return lName;
      }

      public void setSSN(String ssn)
      {
        nbrSSN = ssn;
      }

      public String getSSN()
      {
        return nbrSSN;
      }

      public void setStatus(char status)
      {
        acctStatus = status;
      }

      public char getStatus()
      {
        return acctStatus;
      }

      public void setBalance(double begBalance)
      {
        balance = begBalance;
      }

      public double getBalance()
      {
        return balance;
      }



      public abstract void debitAccount(double amount);

      public abstract void creditAccount(double amount);

      public abstract void deposit(double amount);

      public abstract void withdraw(double amount);




    }
```

And this is one of the classes that I have for savings. I need a few other classes, but I was stuck on the difference in setting up the credit and debit compared to the deposit and withdrawal if that makes sense.

```
    public class Savings extends Account
    {
      private double intRate;

      public Savings(String first, String last, String ssn, double begBalance, double rate)
      {
        super(first, last, ssn, begBalance);

        setRate(rate);

      }

      Public Savings(String first, String last, String ssn, double rate)
      {
        super(first, last, ssn);

        setRate(rate);

      }


      public void setRate(double rate)
      {
        intRate = rate;
      }

      public double getRate()
      {
        return intRate;
      }


      @Override
      public void debitAccount(double amount)
      {

      }

      @Override
      public void creditAccount(double amount)
      {

      }

      @Override
      public void deposit(double amount)
      {
      balance += amount;
      }

      @Override
      public void withdraw(double amount)
      {
        if(amount > balance)
        {
          balance = -1;
        }
        else
        {
          balance -= amount;
        }

        }



  @Override
  public void postMonthly()
  {
  ((intRate/12)* balance);
  }
}
```

I haven't setup the postMonthly method yet, but she wants us to calculate the interest for the month based on the current balance and intRate and it invokes creditAcct(), passing result of interest calculation, which confused me a bit too. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: " since I would assume it would be the same as deposit and withdrawal, but I don't believe it is" -- Well, pick one. You can't write code until you decide what it is going to do. Also, do you have a *specific* question? "I'm stuck, please help" is a bit broad for a Stack Overflow question.

Comment: If you don't have any clear specification of what the methods should do, then the test harness is probebly this specification. It tells what is expected after calling these methods. Side note: please use full names instead of abbraviations: `balance` instead of `begBalance` (whatever this might mean), `firstName` instead of `fName`, etc.

Comment: Ok, I was just trying to see if anyone has worked with the debit and credit part of an account class, because everywhere I look it's being used as a deposit and withdrawal type system. However, my teacher is wanting it to be used as like a debit to the account, like how it's used in accounting. She doesn't even call those methods in the test harness, or I would look that way, which I have. Also, the teacher is the one that had those names setup that way, I go by what she wants. I am still learning here, obviously, so I was just putting it out there to see if anyone had suggestions.

Comment: I figured it out, nevermind.